# Helpers in stateless functional components

Tags: reactjs

With the introduction of Stateless functional components in react we have multiple ways to add helper methods to our component. What is the defined standard practice in regards to helper functions?

The helper-functionis not indended to be a general utility function. (which means it is only used for this specific component)

Place them inside the component-function?

```
export const myComponent = (props) => {
    const myHelper = (value) => {
        // Insert logic
    };       

    return <div>{myHelper(props.mystate.value)}</div>;
};
```

Place them outside the function, but in the same file?

```
const myHelper = (value) => {
    // Insert logic
};

export const myComponent = (props) => {    
    return <div>{myHelper(props.mystate.value)}</div>;
};
```

Or is there an alternative way that is commonly used?

Comment: Is helper specific to "that" single component only? Leave it in same file. Otherwise, export it from helpers file and import where needed.

Comment: Adding to this, remember, if the function uses anything from outside its own scope, it's not pure, it's kind of stateful

Comment: You should avoid defining a function inside the function component because a new function will be created each time the functional component is called.

For this reason you should either pass the function as a prop or define it outside the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you intend to reuse the helper function, put it outside the stateless component function, either in same file or another, and export it:

```
export const myHelper = (value) => {
    // Insert logic
};
```

Otherwise, it's up to you to decide - whatever makes sense to keep things organized.

Comment: Although it's up to you to decide, prefer outside of the component. Otherwise, the function is recreated on each render which can lead to performance issues and re-rendering all the down your component tree.

Answer (score 19):

If you put the helper function inside the component function, everytime the component function gets executed, it will create a new instance of the helper function and after the function was executed the instance possibly gets garbage collected. So typically I would put it outside.

Of course there are exceptions, if you use an arrow function, you might need the lexical scope and therefor put it inside the component function, but if it's a pure function, I would say it should go outside.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to the question here.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this, if you want to keep your stateless component pure:

```
const helpers = { helper: text => text.toUpperCase() }

const makeGreeter = helpers => props => <div>helpers.helper(props.greet)</div>;
const greeter = makeGreeter(helpers);
export default greeter;
```

This way, your component is a closure encapsulating its own helpers and it has predictable behavior.

As a note: If you modify `helper`, and you could, because objects are mutable, `greeter` wouldn't be a pure function.